# Using JSTL, jsp, Jquery to create nested comment (Java servlet)

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, jstl

I created the JavaBean for Comments and CommentDAO, and I successfully send them to jsp file. However, I would like to create a nested structure by adding padding left to the element but I couldn't add the comments that are grandchild of the parent comment.

Here is the code:

```
public class Comments {
    private int commentID;
    private String comment;
    private int parentID;
    private int userID;
    private int articleID;
    private Boolean hide;
    private int commentDepth;
    private int childCount;

    public void setCommentDepth(int commentDepth) {
        this.commentDepth = commentDepth;
    }

    public int getCommentDepth() {
        return commentDepth;
    }

    public void setChildCount(int childCount) {
        this.childCount = childCount;
    }

    public int getChildCount() {
        return childCount;
    }

    public void setHide(Boolean hide){ this.hide=hide; }

    public Boolean getHide(){ return hide; }

    public void setArticleID(int articleID) {
        this.articleID = articleID;
    }

    public int getArticleID() {
        return articleID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setCommentID(int commentID) {
        this.commentID = commentID;
    }

    public int getCommentID() {
        return commentID;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setParentID(int parentID) {
        this.parentID = parentID;
    }

    public int getParentID() {
        return parentID;
    }
}
```

Change comments to ThreadedComments which contains childCount and commentDepth

```
public static List<Comments> toThreadedComments(List<Comments> comments){

        //The resulting array of threaded comments
        List<Comments> threaded = new ArrayList<>();

        //An array used to hold processed comments which should be removed at the end of the cycle
        List<Comments> removeComments = new ArrayList<Comments>();

        //get the root comments first (comments with no parent)
        for(int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i++){
            Comments c = comments.get(i);
            if(c.getParentID() == 0){
                c.setCommentDepth(0); //A property of Comment to hold its depth
                c.setChildCount(0); //A property of Comment to hold its child count
                threaded.add(c);
                removeComments.add(c);
            }
        }

        if(removeComments.size() > 0){
            //clear processed comments
            comments.removeAll(removeComments);
            removeComments.clear();
        }

        int depth = 0;
        //get the child comments up to a max depth of 10
        while(comments.size() > 0 && depth <= 10){
            depth++;
            for(int j = 0; j< comments.size(); j++){
                Comments child = comments.get(j);
                //check root comments for match
                for(int i = 0; i < threaded.size(); i++){
                    Comments parent = threaded.get(i);
                    if(parent.getCommentID() == child.getParentID()){
                        parent.setChildCount(parent.getChildCount()+1);
                        child.setCommentDepth(depth+parent.getCommentDepth());
                        threaded.add(i+parent.getChildCount(),child);
                        removeComments.add(child);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(removeComments.size() > 0){
                //clear processed comments
                comments.removeAll(removeComments);
                removeComments.clear();
            }
        }

        return threaded;
    }
```

function to get allArticleComments:

```
 public static List<Comments> getArticleComment(int articleID) {
        List<Comments> articleComments = new ArrayList<>();
****connection to database and return all comments with the same ArticleID.

}
```

Jstl to print the nested comments: (I cant figure out how to use recursive function using javascript)

```
<c:if test="${threadedComments !=null}">
  <c:forEach items="${threadedComments}" var="comments">
    <c:if test="${comments.childCount > 0}">
      <p>${comments.commentID}: ${comments.comment}</p>
        <c:forEach items="${threadedComments}" var="nestedcomments">
          <c:if test="${nestedcomments.parentID == comments.commentID}">
            <p style="padding-left: ${nestedcomments.commentDepth * 10}%">${nestedcomments.commentID}:${nestedcomments.comment}</p>
          </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

send JavaBean from servlet:

```
List<Comments> allComments = CommentDAO.getArticleComment(articleID);
                List<Comments> threadedComments = CommentDAO.toThreadedComments(allComments);

                request.setAttribute("threadedComments" , threadedComments);
```

Comment: The top few code should be all fine, just second last on how to structure the nested comment in jsp file.

Comment: I think you should add list<comments> inside your command class instead of parentID , see more about [composite pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/composite_pattern.htm).

Comment: It's in the mysql database, if I added list<comments>. I have to add the comment to parent class?